# Listbox with list values critery for report

Tags: ms-access, vba, report

I have a listbox with list of values:

"EM-LU-0002";"EM-DR-0005"

I sei for filter a report with this list i use:

```
Dim filtro As String

filtro = "CodProduto = '" & Me.ListaProdutoSelecionado & "';"

DoCmd.OpenReport "rltProdutos", acViewReport, , filtro
```

But dont work.
I need help.

Answer (score 0):

Your report has a property called "Filter On Load" in the Data tab. Change this from "No" to "Yes".

Comment: Not only that, I think my code is wrong because it only returns codproduto = ";